# GitHub Push Fails

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a android project in my GitHub repository. but it does not works. It shows some error as well as hints. the error and hint is given below:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jahid-csedu/medcino.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What should be the solution for this?

Comment: Pull before you push.

Comment: also doesn't work after pull

Comment: Do you still get the same error? Did you make sure the pull was succesfull? You may have local changes you still need to commit before pull succeeds. The pull can result in merge conflicts that you first have to solve and commit before you can finally push.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull the code from the repository
command is git pull origin branchname

try this after that try to push the code then it will work.

This error is because any other person who worked on the same project might have changed some code in the project so you have to pull the code before pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

answer is in error...
at first try

```
git pull https://github.com/jahid-csedu/medcino.git
```

and then `push`

Comment: I have pulled then push. but also shows the same message